# Displaying products based on the custom taxonomy created

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am working on an online shop project.I created a wordpress custom taxonomy named 'gender' and added two terms in that called men's  and women's , and added the taxonomy in products.When I add each product ,I select the taxonomy ie,either men's or women's.Also created a custom menu to display the taxonomy on the menubar.When I click on men's,the products that were under men's category should display and when select women's,the curresponding products should be displayed.I am new to php and wordpress,I am stuck with how to display the curresponding produts related to the taxonomy terms.Please help....

```
enter code here

<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Gender Category Tab
* Description: Creates a gender category.
* Version: 1.0.1
*/
if(!defined('ABSPATH')) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

//hook into the init action and call create_gender_hierarchical_taxonomy when it fires

add_action( 'init', 'create_gendercategory_taxonomy', 0 );

function create_gendercategory_taxonomy() {

// Labels part for the GUI

$labels = array(
'name'                      => _x( 'gender', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name'             => _x( 'gender', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items'              =>  __( 'Search gender' ),
'popular_items'             => __( 'Popular gender' ),
'all_items'                 => __( 'All gender' ),
'parent_item'               => null,
'parent_item_colon'         => null,
'edit_item'                 => __( 'Edit gender' ), 
'update_item'               => __( 'Update gender' ),
'add_new_item'              => __( 'Add New gender' ),
'new_item_name'             => __( 'New gender Name' ),
'add_or_remove_items'       => __( 'Add or remove gender' ),
'choose_from_most_used'     => __( 'Choose from the most used gender' ),
'menu_name'                 => __( 'gender' ),
 ); 



 register_taxonomy('gender','product',array(
'labels'                    => $labels,
'hierarchical'              => true,
'public'                    => true,
'show_ui'                   => true,
'show_admin_column'         => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'         => true,
'show_tagcloud'             => true,
'query_var'                 => true,
'rewrite'                   => array( 'slug' => 'topic' ),

 ));
```

}
   add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'gender_clothing_menu_item',10,2);

```
function gender_clothing_menu_item( $items, $args ) {
  $taxo_terms = get_terms( 'gender', array(     'hide_empty' => 0) );
  $allProducts=site_url()."/shop";
  $items.="<li class='menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-  children dropdown'><a href='".$allProducts."'>Clothings</a>";
 $items.="<ul class='sub-menu'>";
 foreach($taxo_terms as $term)
 {
  $items.='<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="">'  .$term->name. '</a></li>';
 }
 $items.="</ul>";
 $items.="</li>";

return $items;

 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
foreach($taxo_terms as $term)
 {  $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
  $items.='<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">'  .$term->name. '</a></li>';
 }
```

and create file into your theme with name:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
```

and do code to display product